# Possible to enrich data in a collection?

Tags: getstream-io

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if it's possible to enrich data in a collection or if there is another recommended best practice to achieve the same result.

Consider the following example:

```js
const user = await client.user(userId).get();

const object = await client.collections.add({
  'Message',
  messageId,
  message: {
    contents: 'Hello world!',
    user // this fails with the error "Converting circular structure to JSON"
  }
});

await feed.addActivity({
  actor,
  verb,
  object
});

// I want the objects enriched in this request to also contain the enriched user object
await feed.get({ enrich: true });
```

Comment: I suppose I may not need to store user data on the collection itself. Reading this info from the actor on the activity item might be enough, I'm just still wrapping my head around what this would end up looking like once I introduce things like reactions or other possible actions against a message. Nevertheless, I'm still curious whether this is possible or not.